# Changing a mat-select default option under a condition?

Tags: angular

```
<mat-form-field  appearance="outline" class="calendarfilter">
    <mat-label>Calendario</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="serverEvent.idCalendario" name="idcalendario" [disabled]="`serverEvent.categoria == eventCategories.Pratica`">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let calendar of calendars" [value]="calendar.id">
        {{calendar.descrizione}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

This is a mat-select I'm using for an angular project. It chooses between two options, that I'll name 1 and 2.
Basically what I need to do is to make the default option the number 2 if `serverEvent.categoria == eventCategories.Pratica` , while leaving it as a normal select otherwise. Is it possible? I'm still a newbie with angular so I'm not sure about it.

EDIT: By leaving it as normal I mean to be able to choose both option. In fact, if `serverEvent.categoria == eventCategories.Pratica`, what it should do is it should be disabled with option 2 chosen by default, so that you can only choose that option.

Comment: By "leaving it as a normal select otherwise" you mean it should select Option 1 on default?

Comment: @Remy I've made an edit

Comment: Isn't it enough to set `serverEvent.idCalendario` in the .ts-file to the `calendar.id` of option 2? Since it is a two-way-binding. Does this work? I think with `[(value)]="serverEvent.idCalendario"` it would work, from docs: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#getting-and-setting-the-select-value

Comment: @Remy Yeah, thanks a lot it worked! That was simple, but being a newbie I didn't really thought about it and made several more difficult attempts.